# Por que o Firefox não exibe imagens WEBP?

Tags: imagem, firefox, webp

Fiz um slide em um site onde eu utilizo imagens que foram me passadas em formato WEBP.

Achei que estava tudo certo, pois no Chrome tudo estava funcionando. Porém percebi que no Firefox (versão 57.0.4) as imagens não são exibidas.

Eu gostaria de saber:

- por que o Firefox não renderiza as imagens WEBP? Falta suporte?
- WEBP é apenas experimental (essa pergunta precisa ser respondida considerando que estamos no ano de 2018)?
- Quais navegadores têm suporte?

Comment: Parece que o firefox não tem suporte ao webp ainda. Mas é possivel fazer funcionar nele: http://www.habilelabs.io/webp-format-speed-improvement-making-cross-broswer-compatible/

Comment: Aparentemente são poucos que possuem suporte, dê uma olhada no caniuse https://caniuse.com/#search=webp

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/46wxye/why_is_firefox_still_not_supporting_webp/

Answer (score 7):

**por que o Firefox não renderiza as imagens WEBP? Falta suporte?**

R: Sim, não tem suporte.

**Quais navegadores têm suporte?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**WEBP é apenas experimental (essa pergunta precisa ser respondida considerando que estamos no ano de 2018)?**

R: Sobre ele ser experimental, acredito que não pois o Chrome dá suporte ao WebP desde a versão 23.

No Firefox por exemplo existe um tópico relacionado ao suporte do WebP para o browser:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1294490

Answer (score 1):

Atualizando a resposta, já que agora o Firefox suporta WebP.

### Suporte

O Firefox possui suporte a imagens `.webp` desde Janeiro de 2019, a partir da versão 65 ([veja o anúncio](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/01/firefox-65-webp-flexbox-inspector-new-tooling/)). É possível ver todos os navegadores que suportam `.webp` no site [Can I use...](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp). Nas versões atuais listadas, apenas o Internet Explorer, Safari, iOS Safari e o KaiOS Browser não possuem esse suporte.

Estado de suporte em Junho/2020:
[image: Suporte dos navegadores ao WebP em Junho/2020]

<sup>1</sup> Suporte parcial. Refere-se a não suportar imagens sem perdas (*lossless*), *alpha* e imagens WebP animadas.

<sup>2</sup> Suporte parcial. Refere-se ao não suporte de imagens WebP animadas.

### Sobre o WebP

Sobre o WebP ser experimental, a resposta é não. Ele foi criado em 30 de Setembro de 2010, sendo experimental na época, mas em 2018 (data da pergunta) já era algo "concreto". Não encontrei uma data em que ele passou a ser considerado "em produção", porém a primeira versão do Google Chrome a suportá-la (de acordo com o Can I use) foi a 32, lançada em 2014.

O WebP é apenas um formato como todos os outros, porém possui características que o fez ser adotado cada vez mais na Internet, para conseguir transferir imagens com menos bytes com qualidade similar, mais informações podem ser encontradas no [Site do Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/), no [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/faq) e [neste artigo](https://www.keycdn.com/support/webp-support). Vale ressaltar que WebP é um formato Open Source.

### E o Internet Explorer e Safari?

Bom, visto que o [Internet Explorer não possui mais suporte da Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-ie-support), podemos ver que o [Edge suporta WebP](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/status/webpimageformat/), então a Microsoft fez "a parte dela".

Já sobre a Apple, apesar de algumas notícias de 2016 ([cnet](https://www.cnet.com/news/apple-ios-macos-tests-googles-webp-graphics-to-speed-up-web/) e [MacMagazine](https://macmagazine.uol.com.br/post/2016/07/19/apple-esta-testando-suporte-ao-formato-de-imagens-webp-do-google-em-novas-versoes-beta-do-safari/)) relatarem que a Apple estava testando o suporte ao WebP, não surgiu nenhuma novidade desde então.

Algumas discussões foram geradas no fórum da Apple questionando sobre o motivo de não ter esse suporte ([1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251231940), [2](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250755493), [3](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8342639) e [4](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250073758)), mas nenhuma resposta concreta. Assim como foi com o Firefox, só o tempo dirá se o Safari terá isso, mas provavelmente ainda não foi implementado porque esse formato foi criado pela Google e as empresas têm suas "intrigas".